# How can I convert the value I get with datetimepicker to date and time?

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```
var innerDate = document.getElementById('datetimepicker3').value;
```

The format I get from this line is: innerDate: "2021/07/07 14:00"

But I need to parse the date and time information here. How can I convert Start Date and Start Time into two separate variables?

Comment: try using momentjs or Luxon , these are great libraries for manipulating dates and for changing formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var innerDate = new Date(document.getElementById('datetimepicker3').value)
```

Or you can attach an event handler to get the date whenever it changes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#datetimepicker3").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        let date = e.date;
        console.log(date);
        // no need to convert to a date
   });
</script>
```

Comment: @try123 check this out!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to parse that string with [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and then depending on your needs either [get the individual parts](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) for calculations or apply needed [formatting](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Example available at https://jsfiddle.net/Ly6qen3w/

```
let innerDateInput = "2021/07/07 14:00";
let innerDateMoment = moment(innerDateInput, "YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm");

console.log("Date:"+innerDateMoment.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log("Time:"+innerDateMoment.format("hh:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple get that in different variable using various methods that are provided by JavaScript to get everything.

You can do is(id it's a date object else you have to convert it to date object)

```
let startDate = new Date(innerDate).getDate() + "/" + new Date(innerDate).getMonth() + "/" + new Date(innerDate).getFullYear();

let startTime = new Date("2021/07/07 14:00").getHours() +":"+ new Date("2021/07/07 14:00").getMinutes()
```

If you want something else you can retrieve that too with methods such as milliseconds,UFC time etc.

If you find this messy I would suggest you to use moment.js.
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: just +1 for months as it gives 1 less value.